# id is autoincremented in database but is not set in the entity in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have an id field which is autogenerated:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;
```

In my entity, I define the sequence generation as:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "pes_id_seq")
@Table(name = "pes")
```

Now, when I save the entity using:

```
repository.save(entity);
```

And try to get id of the newly inserted row like this:

```
System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

It always displays 1. However, in database, id(serial field) is incremented as expected.

Comment: can you provide a complete code example from instantiation of the entities until the test that the ids are different?

Comment: Did you flush the session to commit the save?

Comment: when I try to flush using repository.getSession().flush() , it shows session is closed!

Comment: @JensSchauder: the remaining code is as usual. I think the problem is with id generation.

Comment: I think you want `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` with a `generator=` entry, IIRC. Check the docs for details.

Comment: @Florescent Ticker if the code is as usual, your JVM or OS is broken, because the usual version of the code works. ;-)

Comment: Why you need to have  @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) and @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "pes_id_seq") for the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) type ? . mean you can just use @id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) which is enough to create id in postgres

Comment: @Mani: I removed that. Still the problem prevails.

Comment: @JensSchauder: You know if the code was as usual working, I would not have been here with these awesome guyz ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Repository.save` will save the entity passed as parameter , but it will not update / merge(JPA terms) the passed argument.
Let say example

```
repository.save(entity);

System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

Will always return the value of entity id before it saving  . You have to get the returned object which is newly created/managed by Repository which will have correct Id after saving.

```
entity = repository.save(entity);

System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

Comment: well, repository.save(entity) returns void and if I use hibernates's save, it returns Serializable(don't know)...but it doesn't return entity.

Comment: i am not sure what does mean by repository here. if its Spring JPA Data api. then it would return Entity . if you refer hibernate session ( i expect the variable name changed to session) then it would return the newly created Id. So all the way you will get the newly created id.